# Good practices salt-stack versus ansible

Tags: salt-stack

I am new to *Saltstack*, I have some history with *Ansible*. And I am
surprise by the "*standard*" *saltstack* formulas.

I will use *Tomcat* as example.

In *Ansible*, in the *Tomcat* role, I add dependency to *Java*.
So in the future, I don't need to remenber that *Tomcat* depends on *Java*. I just run
the *Tomcat* role to deploy *Tomcat* and *Java* if necessary. (See [ansible-examples on github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/tomcat-standalone/roles/tomcat/tasks/main.yml))

In *Saltstack*, in the *Tomcat* formula, I suppose that *Java* is installed.
When I need to install *Tomcat*, I must install *Java* first with another formula.
(See [saltstack formula on github](https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/tomcat-formula/blob/master/tomcat/init.sls))

The *Saltstack* method seems less usable and robust.
Everyone knows that *Java* is required for *Tomcat* but for my internal
applications/servers, these dependencies are not so clear.

Ansible (install Java with yum or call another role)

```
---
- name: Install Java 1.7
  yum: name=java-1.7.0-openjdk state=present
```

```
---
- name: Install Java 1.7
  include_role: java7
```

Salttack: the pillar should contain the Java home directory, so Java must be installed before the Tomcat installation

```
{% from "tomcat/map.jinja" import tomcat with context %}
{% set tomcat_java_home = tomcat.java_home %}
{% set tomcat_java_opts = tomcat.java_opts %}
```

So, my question is: Should I follow the *saltstack* standard ? Or should I call formula from my formula ?
Any others solutions ?

Thanks